# inverse and contrapositive of the statement (p ∧ q) → r?

Tags: logic

how do I write the inverse and contrapositive of the statement (p ∧ q) → r?

Is the contrapositive ~(p ∧ q) → ~r?

Comment: The contrapositive of $A\to B$ is $\lnot B\to\lnot A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that'd be the *inverse*; the contrapositive here is ~r → ~(p ∧ q). Note that not only did I negate both sides, I switched the order.

For some intuition, try considering the contrapositive of the plain English statement "If this is a rose, it is a flower".

Comment: And by De Morgan's Laws, the contrapositive is also ~r → (~p) ∨ (~q), right?

Comment: @Geoffrey, that is *equivalent to* the contrapositive, by de Morgan, but it is still a different *formula*. (And if we don't distinguish between equivalent but different formulae, then speaking about "contrapositive" in the first place becomes rather pointless).

Comment: I think it makes more sense to say that all three statements are "logically equivalent"  (i.e. any of them alone immediately implies the other two). Talking about the contrapositive is one of the few cases in math where the distinction matters, since the contrapositive of the sentence A → B is _defined_ to be ~B → ~A and only that.